# How to fix problem of Undefined index: sku during custom import in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento

1. Create a custom import adapter extending `Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\Entity\AbstractEntity`
2. Add valid columns in getValidColumnNames() functione.
3. Create CSV file with columns stated above Go to System > Import
4. Select adapter from "Entity Type" dropdown.
5. Select your CSV file in "Select File to Import" field.
6. Click on "Check Data" button.

Follow this link (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19761) and its working fine after adding SKU in CSV with a dummy content.

```
const PINCODE = 'pincode';
const DELIVERY_STATUS = 'delivery_status';
const TABLE_Entity = 'pincode_checker';
protected $validColumnNames = [
    self::PINCODE,
    self::DELIVERY_STATUS,
];
```

Notice: Undefined index: sku in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Magentonew/vendo/magento/module-import-export/Model/Import/Entity/AbstractEntity.php on line 411

Comment: How we can import custom csv to custom table without adding sku  in csv and import adapter file as per  solution in given link (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19761).

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by adding if condition to Sku as mentioned  in the below link.
(https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/22180/commits/d23dd1ed5df664dcfbe79106058049e7e0b1e7fc)